# How can I loop a line of code until the user types the correct answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner and i can't understand that how can I loop a line until the user types that correct answer and then it breaks. For ex.

````
ask = int(input("How much rice do you want? "))
price_of_1kg = 50
total = ask*price_of_1kg
print("This is the price")
print(f"Value: ${total}")
pay = int(input("Pay this price mentioned above "))
while True:
    if pay == total:
        print("good")
        break
    if pay != total:
        int(input("Hey!! Pay the exact amount "))
        break

print("Thank you, visit again")

```

I want to loop the second if statement until the user enters the correct amount
````

Comment: Well, try to think about it logically. In your own words, what is `break` used for? When should it happen in your loop? When should it not happen?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
ask = int(input("How much rice do you want? "))
price_of_1kg = 50
total = ask*price_of_1kg
print("This is the price")
print(f"Value: ${total}")
pay = int(input("Pay this price mentioned above "))
while pay != total:
    pay = int(input("Hey!! Pay the exact amount "))

print("Thank you, visit again")
```